# Why doesn't this ruby regex work?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a very simple regex task that has left me confused (and just when I thought I was starting to get the hang of them too). I just want to check that a string consists of 11 digits. The regex I have used for this is `/\d{11}/`. My understanding is that this will give a match if there are exactly (no more and no less than) 11 numeric characters (but clearly my understanding is wrong).

Here is what happens in irb:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :018 > "33333333333" =~ /\d{11}/
 => 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :019 > "3333333333" =~ /\d{11}/
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :020 > "333333333333" =~ /\d{11}/
 => 0
```

So while I get an appropriate match for an 11 digit string and an appropriate no-match for a 10 digit string, I am getting a match on a 12 digit string! I would have thought `/\d{11,}/` would be the regex to do this.

Can anyone explain my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), the assumption "no more, no less" is incorrect.

```
/\d{5}/
```

matches

```
foo12345bar
   ^
   +---here
```

and

```
s123456yargh13337
 ^^         ^
 |+---here  |
 +----here  |
      here--+
```

So, instead use:

```
/^\d{5}$/
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. I did the recommended reading and realized that an even better regex would be /\A\d{11}\Z/ but that's just being picky.

Comment: @brad True. `\b\d{11}\b` is yet another way.

Answer (score 1):

The 12 digit string contains the substring that matches your regexp. If you want an exact match, write the regexp like this: `/^\d{11}$/`.